# Is possible in a single pass build a FULL JOIN for a in-memory structure (not using sql!)

Tags: join, rust, nested-loops, relational-algebra, relational

I'm building a in-memory columnar relational engine. For extract the values I want to do late materialization where I collect the positions/indices where a match was found and at the end collect the values.

Now implementing joins I fail to see how do a general join algorithm that cover all the other cases. Left, Right & Inner are easy, but FULL/Outer not. This is my naive implementation with nested-loops:

```
pub fn join(&self, compare:&BoolExpr) -> JoinPos
{
    //Allocate at least for inner joins...
    let total = cmp::max(self.left.len(), self.right.len());

    let mut cols_left  = Vec::with_capacity(total);
    let mut cols_right = Vec::with_capacity(total);
    let mut found = false;

    while !self.left.eof() {
        let left = self.left.tuple();
        while !self.right.eof() {
            let right = self.right.tuple();
            if compare(&left, &right) {
                //A match found. Record positions of both cursors
                cols_left.push(self.left.pos() as isize);
                cols_right.push(self.right.pos() as isize);
                found = true;
            }
            self.right.next();
        }
        //Not found a single match at the right cursor..
        if !found {
            cols_left.push(self.left.pos() as isize);
            cols_right.push(-1);
        }
        found = false;
        self.left.next();
        self.right.first();
    }

    JoinPos {
        left:cols_left,
        right:cols_right,
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that I can find when the left was not found in the right but not the opposite without another pass:

```
Input:
L= [1, 2, 3]
R= [2, 3, 4]

Result. It capture the positions that match. -1 if not found
L | R
======
1   -1
2   1
3   2
-1  3
```

Thanks to @philipxy I have a working solution:

```
pub fn join(&self, compare:&BoolExpr) -> JoinPos
{
    let total = cmp::max(self.left.len(), self.right.len());

    let mut right_not_founds = HashSet::new();
    let mut cols_left  = Vec::with_capacity(total);
    let mut cols_right = Vec::with_capacity(total);
    let mut found = false;
    let mut first = true;

    while !self.left.eof() {
        let left = self.left.tuple(&self.cols_left);
        while !self.right.eof() {
            let right = self.right.tuple(&self.cols_right);
            if first {
                right_not_founds.insert(self.right.pos());
            }

            if compare(&left, &right) {
                cols_left.push(self.left.pos() as isize);
                cols_right.push(self.right.pos() as isize);
                right_not_founds.remove(&self.right.pos());

                found = true;
            }
            self.right.next();
        }
        if !found {
            cols_left.push(self.left.pos() as isize);
            cols_right.push(-1);
        }
        found = false;
        first = false;
        self.left.next();
        self.right.first();
    }

    for pos in right_not_founds {
        cols_left.push(-1);
        cols_right.push(pos as isize);
    }

    JoinPos {
        left:cols_left,
        right:cols_right,
    }
}
```

Comment: Dozens of published database textbooks are free online in pdf. Where did you learn what you know of relational join implementation/optimization? Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are trying to ask. Do you want to know only about variations of a nested loops algorithm? If so, is storing data & looping over it a "pass"? (And why do you even care about one more pass, since you already pass over the right table for every left table row?) Are you asking about *any* algorithm? We can join by sorting with one "pass" per input then "merging" in one "pass" per sorted structure--is this "single pass"? PS  What exactly are your input & output structures? What is your cost model? Please read & act on [mcve]. Please tag with your language.

Comment: I asking exactly what the title say. How run the full outer join and if is possible to do it in a single pass (ie: comparing only once per row). The example is done in the Input/Result part. Was a mistake to put the rust code I have?

Comment: Re "Was it a mistake to include the rust code": Your question is about an algorithm so it is good that you give code & language. But we should be able to cut & paste & run code, including declarations & example input, and preferably cut & paste & compare output & desired output. And it should have a clear specification & explanation. (That is the essence of what the MCVE link says.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full join returns inner join tuples union unmatched left table tuples extended by nulls union unmatched right table tuples extended by nulls.

Currently your code outputs left join tuples. Each iteration of the outer loop outputs more tuples that are in the inner join or it outputs the null-extension of a left table tuple that did not match any right table tuple. To output full join tuples you must also output the null-extension of each right table tuple that did not match any left table tuple. You can do this as follows: Define a set variable before the loops. It will eventually contain all positions/indices for right table tuples that did not match any left table tuple. Immediately before the `if compare`, if it is the first iteration of the outer loop then insert the right tuple position/index into the set. Inside the `if  compare`'s nested block remove the right tuple position/index from the set.